# PostgreSQL installation issue on windows

Tags: windows-10, postgresql

I was trying to install PostgreSQL on my windows system but an error is occurring again and again.

Here is the screenshot while the installation process:

[image]

Comment: Run as `Administrator` and make sure UAC is enabled in Windows

Comment: Have done this but it didn't help either

Comment: Does your user have read/write permissions on the directory in question?  Does the user in question have ownership over the directory in question?  Please provide all vital information as an edit to your question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Open it with Administrators rights by right clicking the install file and left click "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR".

Comment: I have done the respective also but still, the problem is occurring

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with the installers for the versions 11.5 and 10.10 on Windows 10 x64. Apparently, this is an installer issue.

However, I have found a download link for the version 11.2.1 on another website which works for me: https://www.netzwelt.de/software-download/26666-postgresql.html